# Length of sub element calculation in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FRUIT>
    <APPLE>
        <COLOR RED = "TRUE"/>
        <TASTE SWEET = "TRUE" />
    </APPLE>
    <ORANAGE>
        <COLOR ORANGE = "TRUE"/>
        <TASTE SWEET = "FALSE" />
    </ORANAGE>
</FRUIT>
```

I need a a Python parser for XML similar to the above element.
I need to calculate lengths of sub elements like **apple**, i.e. COLOR and TASTE should be calculated in length.  I tried:

```
tree = ET.parse("abc.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print len(root.findall(child.tag))
    print child.tag
```

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried yourself?

Comment: tree = ET.parse("abc.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
 print len(root.findall(child.tag))
 print child.tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a way to calculate sub element.

count = 0
for child in root:
    k = 0
    j = 0
    while (k < 1):
      try:
         x = root[i][j]
         count = count+j + 1
      expect:
         k = 2